# I need to implement a function that can be used multiple times

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, swift3, singleton

I have one swift function and that I want to convert into objective C can any one help me to convert it? Any help will be appreciated

```
     func getdata(_ send: NSString)
    {

        let url=URL(string:send as String)
        do
        {
            let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
            let allContacts = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
            print(allContacts)
            if let musicJob = allContacts["Attendance"] as? [Any], !musicJob.isEmpty
            {
                print(musicJob)
                dataArray = allContacts["Attendance"] as! NSArray
                print(dataArray)

            }
}
           { let send: String = String(format:"http://182.18.182.91/RaosMobileService/Service1.svc/GetStudentAttendance_ByMonth/%@/%@/1/%d/2017",loadedUserName,studentId,row+1)
            self.getdata(send as NSString)
}
```

> How to convert this into objective C, Any help pls. I need to use this  func getdata(_ send: NSString)
>   multiple times

Answer (score 0):

**NSJSONSerialization** in **Objective-c**

TRY 1:   If Json return Array

```
 -(void)getdata:(NSString *)send
    {
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:send];
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSError *e = nil;
        NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

        if (!jsonArray) {
            NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
        } else {
            for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
                NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
            }
        }
    }
```

TRY 2: If Json return Dictinary

```
-(void)getdata:(NSString *)send
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:send];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSDictionary *res     = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves|| NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",res);
 }
```

**To call Method:**

```
  NSString *send = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://182.18.182.91/RaosMobileService/Service1.svc/GetStudentAttendance_ByMonth/%@/%@/1/%d/2017"];
    [self getdata:send];
```

Comment: This one too pls 
 let send: String = String(format:"http://xyz/%@/%@/1/%d/2017",loadedUserName,studentId,row+1)
            self.getdata(send as NSString)